# `if` statement using decimal string returns false when it should be true

Tags: ios, swift

When inspecting a text field by overriding the method below in swift:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

the line below returns false when I type in a 1 into the text field

```
var hasLeadingOne = length > 0 && decimalString.characterAtIndex(0) == (1 as unichar)
```

`hasLeadingOne` returns **false** but it should be **true** when I enter 1 into the text field. Moreover, the value of decimalString.characterAtIndex(0) seems to be 49 instead of 1 even when casted as unichar. What am I missing?

Comment: `49` is the ASCII character code for `1`.

Comment: And `unichar` is just a `typealias` for `UInt16`. The name `unichar` makes it sound like it is a character of some kind, but it is just a number.

Comment: so it should be true but it's still returning false

Comment: @Kenney More correctly, `49` is the Unicode value for the character `1`. `characterAtIndex:` works in Unicode, not ASCII. Of course the first 127 ASCII is the same as the first 127 Unicode.

Comment: `decimalString.characterAtIndex(0) == (49 as unichar)` should be `true`, since `49` is the ASCII character code for `1`, as @Kenney pointed out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A suggestion... instead of using the complex boolean test that you've constructed, Swift offers an easy way to check if a `String` begins with a certain sequence of characters: `hasPrefix`. You can simplify your code like this:

```
var hasLeadingOne = decimalString.hasPrefix("1")
```

If you want to use the boolean test that you wrote, I believe that this will work:

```
var hasLeadingOne = length > 0 && decimalString.characterAtIndex(0) == (49 as unichar)
```